# C++ Fatal Error C1382: the PCH file 'file' has been rebuilt since 'obj' was generated. Please rebuild this object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Does anyone encounter this error when compiling in C++?

```
Fatal Error C1382: the PCH file 'file' has been rebuilt since 'obj' was generated. Please rebuild this object
```

I google the solution and msdn suggested me to have to do two things:

> 1. When using /LTCG, the compiler detected a .pch file that is newer than a CIL .obj that points to it. The information in the CIL .obj file is out of date. Rebuild the object.
> 2. C1382 can also occur if you compile with /Yc, but also pass multiple source code files to the compiler. To resolve, do not use /Yc when passing multiple source code files to the compiler.

I did option 1 but the compiler turn it on by itself.

For option 2, how do I know if I am pass multiple souce code files to the compiler?

I cannot turn off the /Yc option as all other projects in my work application turned on /Yc option...only my project has this problem.

Does anyone know a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably already have it set up properly, but double check to make sure that you only have one cpp file set to create the precompiled header and all the rest set to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rebuild the entire solution.

Comment: Yes, I know rebuild works. But sometimes someone check in code which doesn't relate to my project will cause this problem...Rebuild the whole project takes 3-4 hours and incremental build only take 15 minutes. I would like to see if there is some setting that I did it wrong which cause this problem instead of rebuilding it everytime.

Comment: @Kintarō rebuilding the source file of the problematic `.obj` should be enough as well

Comment: Thanks but do you know what cause the .obj to become problematic?

Comment: You might want to look into the http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-care-and-feeding-of-pre-compiled-headers for info about precompiled headers (that's your `.pch` files) and possible problems with them

Comment: Thanks. I turned of the /LTGC flag and rebuild the solution. After that I don't see the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is known bug in VS2005 (Unfortunately I have nothing to reference to). To fix this you should put stdafx.cpp on top of other cpp files in vcproj file. This bug is fixed in VS2008 and later.

E.g. in vcproj you'll have something like this:

```
<Files>
  <Filter Name="Source Files" ...>
    <File RelativePath=".\file1.cpp"> .. </File>
    <File RelativePath=".\file2.cpp"> .. </File>
    <File RelativePath=".\stdafx.cpp"> .. </File>
...
</Filter>    
...
</Files>
```

You should make it:

```
<Files>
  <Filter Name="Source Files" ...>
    <File RelativePath=".\stdafx.cpp"> .. </File>
    <File RelativePath=".\file1.cpp"> .. </File>
    <File RelativePath=".\file2.cpp"> .. </File>
...
</Filter>    
...
</Files>
```

PS

This is floating issue which will happen from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

We have been having this issue at work, when we use QT Moc to make the moc files in a pre-build step and the stdafx.h contents changes, which was being included via a /fi command argument, we found VS2008 Win32 compiler didn't raise this error, but the VS2008 ARMv4i compiler did.

we could add a dependency on stdafx.h to the pre-build step rule, but this didn't solve if the things stdafx.h included changed, so for now re a forced clean/rebuild is our solution.